# Turán number of even cycles with diagonal

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Let $C_{2k}'$ denote the graph that consists of the cycle on $2k$ vertices and one more edge, a chord connecting two opposite, i.e., distance $k$ vertices of the cycle.

> What is known about the Turán number $ex(n,C_{2k}')$?

I am mainly interested in what happens when $k$ is odd and large.

Comment: For $k=2$ and $n\geqslant 4$ it equals $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$, an old result of Erdos

Comment: Isn't that just Mantel's theorem?

Comment: Mantel theorem is about triangle, and Erdos observed that with the same number of edges which guarantees a triangle, there exist two triangles with common edge.

Comment: The answer should be roughly the same as the Turán number of $C_{k+1}$. If $k$ is odd, this will be $O(n^{1+2/(k+1)})$. The case of $k=3$ follows from the main result of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.05485.pdf and $k=5$ from Theorem 1.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.13380.pdf. Larger $k$ might be accessible by similar techniques.